# SVM-Light displays corrupted precision/recall results

Tags: classification, svm

I run SVM-Light classifier but the recall/precision row it outputs seem to be corrupted:

```
Reading model...OK. (20 support vectors read)
Classifying test examples..100..200..done
Runtime (without IO) in cpu-seconds: 0.00
Accuracy on test set: 95.50% (191 correct, 9 incorrect, 200 total)
Precision/recall on test set: 0.00%/0.00%
```

What should I configure to get valid precision and recall?

Comment: How are you running the model?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example (a little piece of code with a little piece of example data)?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that your model's accuracy is high (95.5%) but its precision/recall are 0 shows your learning problem is highly unbalanced. Your data set likely contains most negative class, ~ 95.5%. As a result your model will classify every examples as negative class and achieve 95.5% accuracy but since there is no examples classified as positive class, model's precision/recall are 0.
To avoid that, you need to balance positive/negative class ratio in the training set by sub-sampling negative class or put a high weight on positive class examples.